# ¿Como recorrer un array asociativo desde un archivo de texto externo?

Tags: php, array, wordpress, txt

Espero que estén genial una vez mas.

Les comento: Estoy haciendo un plugin en wordpress que permite al usuario ingresar un itinerario (hecho array asociativo con sus respectivas claves y valores). Cuando el usuario ingresa ese documento de texto, este se guarda mediante la función `move_uploaded_file()` en el directorio `/plugins/[miplugin]/uploads`.

Bien, hasta ahí cero problemas. Pero necesito recorrer ese archivo con un foreach para asi poder obtener sus valores y mostrarlos en pantalla.

He intentado hacer lo siguiente (EDIT: Olvide agregar que utiilzo una función generadora.):

```
<?php
function generator($arr, $filter){
        $active = False;

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if ($active) {
                yield $key => $value;
                continue;
            }
            if ($value == $filtro) {
                yield $key => $value;
                $active = True;

            }
        }
    }

$files = scandir(PLUGINPATH . "\uploads", SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
    $newest_file = $files[0];

    $archivo = fopen(PLUGINPATH . "\uploads\\$newest_file", "r");

    foreach (generator($archivo, "IVAO") as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " => " . $value;
        
    }
    fclose($archivo);
    
}
?>
```

Pero no ha funcionado. El archivo se abre y todo. Pero no puedo recorrerlo. ¿Alguna idea?

Oh, **por si quieren saber que hace el codigo que puse arriba**; basicamente lo que hace es sortear los archivos de mas reciente a mas viejo (Esto teniendo en cuenta que mis archivos tienen la fecha como nombre) y toma el primero de todos ya que la funcion `scandir()` devuelve un array.

**EDIT**

Estuve haciendo busquedas y me encontre con muchas funciones de archivos. A continuacion recalco las mas llamativas y por que **NO** funcionan.

`readfile()`<- Esta hermosa funcion LEE el archivo tal cual esta escrito PERO lo hace directamente en el buffer. De esa forma nos deja sin poder almacenarla en una variable, ya que al momento que se ejecuta la función se imprime en pantalla.

`file_get_contents()`<- Esta función devuelve mi array en String. Por lo tanto no es útil.

`file()` <- Esta funcion (aun asi utilizando los recursos como  FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) sobreescribe mi array con otro array por arriba. Haciendo imposible la asociación de variables. Ya que por ejemplo así se ve el Array correctamente: `"IVAO" => "5454"`.
Pero nuestra función nos la devuelve así: `[5]=>"IVAO"=>"5454"` (Y si soy sincero no se que hacer con eso jeje).

`fopen()` <- Abre el archivo y junto a otras funciones solo devuelve sus lineas delimitadas por el parametro que le de el usuario.

**FUNCIONES QUE AL PARECER FUNCIONAN CORRECTAMENTE SEGÚN LO PEDIDO**

`fread()` <- Lee el archivo perfectamente! ¿Pero que sucede? Pues que devuelve un string. No conozco mas parametros para él. Pero devuelve un string y yo necesito que sea un Array o Objeto para poder iterar sobre él... Aunque creo que se me ocurre algo con **substrings**..

**EDIT 2**
Aquí subo un extracto de mi array. Fue generado con herramientas de internet que generan Arrays desde un archivo .CSV.

```
array (
  'Itinerario 20/Jul/2020 al 30/Jul/2020' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Piloto' => 'Carlitos Mejillon',
      'IVAO' => 'XXX',
      'Aeronave' => 'XXX',
      'Matricula' => 'XXX',
      'HUB' => 'SKBO',
      'One' => 'SKCG',
      'Two' => 'MKJP',
      'Three' => 'TJSJ',
      'Four' => 'TNCC',
      'Five' => 'SKBQ',
      'Six' => 'SKSP',
      'Seven' => 'SKBO',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'Piloto' => 'Mejillon Carlitos',
      'IVAO' => 'XXX',
      'Aeronave' => 'XXX',
      'Matricula' => 'XXX',
      'HUB' => 'SKRG',
      'One' => 'TNCM',
      'Two' => 'KMIA',
      'Three' => 'TXKF',
      'Four' => 'TNCM',
      'Five' => 'TJSJ',
      'Six' => 'MPTO',
      'Seven' => 'SKRG',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'Piloto' => 'Ayuda Dios',
      'IVAO' => 'XXX',
      'Aeronave' => 'XXX',
      'Matricula' => 'XXX',
      'HUB' => 'SKRG',
      'One' => 'MROC',
      'Two' => 'MHTG',
      'Three' => 'CYYZ',
      'Four' => 'KMEN',
      'Five' => 'KLAX',
      'Six' => 'MMMX',
      'Seven' => 'SKRG',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Agradecería todo tipo de ayuda. Juro que estoy perdidisimo

Comment: Puedes incluir un extracto del archivo que intentas leer? (y con que fue generado) El formato de origen es importante para saber que opcion es la mejor para leerlo

Comment: Acabo de editar. Gracias por pasarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El formato indicado corresponde a un PHP array (escrito como código PHP que genera un array), por lo que la manera de leerlo seria:

```
$files = scandir(PLUGINPATH . "/uploads", SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$newest_file = $files[0];
$contents=file_get_contents($newest_file);
$data=eval($contents);
print_r($data);
```

El problema de esto es que la funcion eval es muy peligrosa si se estan leyendo datos de una fuente no confiable (alguien podria colocar cualquier codigo PHP y se ejecutaria en tu servidor). Si tienes seguridad de que el archivo importado es de fuente confiable seria ideal, pero viendo que el archivo es subido por usuario suena un poco inseguro de procesar asi.

De otro modo, te aconsejo que busques alguna herramienta que transforme tu archivo CSV en JSON, este formato es totalmente seguro y se puede leer directamente en PHP usando algo semejante (agregué algunas validaciones para descartar problemas de contenido):

```
$files = scandir(PLUGINPATH . "/uploads", SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$newest_file = $files[0];
$archivo=PLUGINPATH . "/uploads/$newest_file";
$contents=file_get_contents($archivo);
if (!$contents){
  die("Sin contenido en $archivo");
}
$data=json_decode($contents, true);
if (!$data){
   die("JSON Error ". json_last_error());
}
print_r($data);
```

EDIT:

Incluye chequeo de conversion json usando la funcion [`json_last_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-last-error.php)

Hace un buen tiempo atras realice una herramienta de este tipo (Text to JSON Converter) https://fraigo.github.io/text-to-json/

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Igor! Ya mismo lo pruebo cuando llegue a mi domicilio.

Comment: Hola Igor. He intentado lo que me has puesto primeramente con `eval()`. Cuestión que no funciona y me tira error fatal (no se por que, estoy usando ese mismo array). Ahora mismo estoy intentando utilizar `json_decode()` con el JSON que generé con tu pagina (muy bien hecha, por cierto) y me devuelve **NULL**. Segun la documentacion de PHP eso significa que no puede decodificar. ¿Tienes alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: Agregue una secuencia de codigo completa para que verifiques que uses los pasos adecuados. Ademas, un chequeo de que tipo de error da json_decode() si sigue ocurriendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Igor. Ahora mismo lo pruebo y te paso el feedback.

Comment: El error que sale es Error:4. ¿Que será eso? **EDIT**: JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
Hmm

Comment: Añadi alguinas validaciones para descartar problemas de contenido. Puede que no este leyendo el contenido. Verifica que el contenido se esta leyendo (la variable $contenido debe tener el texto a convertir)

Comment: Estoy respondiendo muy rapido y debo parecer muy desesperado jeje. Lo siento por eso.
Acabo de probarlo y sigue diciendo JSON Error: 4.. La variable `$content` tiene la direccion del archivo. Acabo de hacer un `echo $archivo;` Y me tira la ruta exacta.

Comment: La variable $contents deberia tener el contenido del archivo, no la ubicacion. Fijate que debe estar completo incluyendo un `[` o `{` al inicio. Seria de ayuda que publicaras un archivo de ejemplo que estas intentando leer. Si tiene acentos o caracteres especiales, debes asegurar que el archivo se guarda con codificacion UTF-8.

Comment: CREO QUE ACABO DE ENCONTRAR EL PROBLEMA IGOR! Estuve investigando y viendo las propiedades de mi archivo y resulta que se guarda en UTF-8 con BOM. Lo guardé como UTF-8 solamente y FUNCIONA. Pero ahora deberé intentar entender como funcionan estas funciones removedoras de BOM. Igual marcaré tu pregunta como la correcta porque haz solucionado el error principal que era el de hacerme dar cuenta que mi archivo estaba mal. 
Muchas gracias Igor. Te dejo un contacto mio (que ya de por si es publico), por si el dia de mañana necesitás ayuda tambien. Amo aprender :D
**oliviaisadog@protonmail.com**